# Python: Having Trouble trying to use Cycle Function from Sympy on a list

Tags: python, permutation, sympy

I am trying the use the cycle function from Sympy to simplify down a list like so.

```
from sympy.combinatorics import Permutation, Cycle

Cycle(1,2,3)(3,4,5)(7)
```

And the output should be...

Cycle(1, 2, 4, 5, 3)(7)

However, when I try using...

```
a_list = [[1,2,3,4],[4,5,7],[3,4,2]]
b = Cycle(a_list)
print(b)
```

I get this error

'tuple' object is not callable

I know that I am inputting the wrong kind of variable into cycle, but could someone tell me what I can do with Cycle. It is a function that does exactly what I need, I just need to find a way to convert a list into a cycle friendly type. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is your goal to run `Cycle(1,2,3,4)(4,5,7)(3,4,2)` to get an output of `Cycle(1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4)`? If so, you just need to convert the nested list into a nested tuple. If that's what you're looking for I'll try to post an answer telling how to do that.

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm trying to do. Then, I want to convert  that cycle, or the two or three cycle if I end up with one, into a list again.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```py
a_list = [[1,2,3,4],[4,5,7],[3,4,2]]

b = Cycle()
for i in a_list:
    b = b(*tuple(i))
print(b)
```

To convert to a list, try `b.list()`.

---

### Explanation

`tuple(i)` converts `[1,2,3,4]` to `(1,2,3,4)`

Say you have a function `foo`. Running `foo(1,2,3,4)` is the same as running `foo(*(1,2,3,4))`

---

### A simpler example:

```py
a_list = [[1,2], [3,4]]

b = Cycle()
```

On the first iteration (`i = [1,2]`), calling `b(*tuple(i))` is the same as calling `b(1,2)` which, because `b = Cycle()`, is really `Cycle()(1,2)` which is the same as `Cycle(1,2)` according to [the docs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/combinatorics/permutations.html?highlight=cycle#sympy.combinatorics.permutations.Cycle).

On the second iteration (`i = [3,4]`), calling `b(*tuple(i))` is really `b(3,4)` which is `Cycle(1,2)(3,4)`

Hopefully, that example makes some sense. It's a little confusing because there are so many parentheses. If you're still confused, you might want to run through the code step by step (maybe with a debugger) to help understand what happens.

Answer (score 0):

`Cycle` (as described in the docstring) provides some subtle advantages to entry, but if all elements are present in the list of cycles that you have shown, then simply passing them to `Permutation` should suffice.

Remember that order matters:

```
>>> Cycle(1,3)(3,2)
Cycle(1, 2, 3)
>>> Cycle(2,3)(1,3)
Cycle(1, 3, 2)

>>> p = Permutation([[1,3],[3,2]])
>>> Cycle(p)
Cycle(1, 2, 3)
>>> p.list() == _.list() == [0, 2, 3, 1]
```

Note that the Permutation will allow you to explicitly ask for `array_form` or `cyclic_form` whereas Cycle only allows the `list()` method:

```
>>> p.array_form
[0, 2, 3, 1]
>>> p.cyclic_form
[[1, 2, 3]]
```